# not able to load resources, server error 500 django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am getting this error The view poll.views.score didn't return an HttpResponse object.

view.py

```
def score(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            user1 = UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('userid'))
            user1.score = request.GET.get('bjpFan')
            user1.save()
            print user1.score
            return render(request,'poll/poll.html',{'user1':user1})
            return HttpResponse("%s" % user1.score )
```

it was working fine before suddenly its giving this error.

poll.html

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
        var bjpFan=localStorage['bjpFan'];
        var userid = $('#profileId').val();
        alert(userid)
        var total = parseInt(localStorage['total']);

                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/poll/score/",
                                type:"GET",
                                data: {bjpFan:bjpFan,userid:userid}
                            }).done(function(data){
                            alert(data);
                            });
```

Can anyone please help me to get out of this.

Comment: I don't know python but doesn't `return` returns, so looks like your second `return` is never reached. PS: i'm really not sure how this is handled on python, function or block scope?!

Comment: Gettitn error for this line "user1 = UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('userid'))"

Comment: Great to know that but what error do you get???

Comment: I put try and exept,,,,,
try:
                user1 = UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('userid'))
                print "ram"
                user1.score = request.GET.get('bjpFan')
                user1.save()
                print user1.score
                return HttpResponse("%s" % user1.score )
            except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
                print "Gaurav"
                user1=None
        return render(request,'poll/poll.html',{'user1':user1}) Its printing Gaurav not Ram

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have an indentation error. The last line of your view should be lined up with the first `if` statement.

Comment: No thats not working i tried that also,,,,,, the above same code was working previously,,,,,

Comment: Really, it wasn't: or it was but only by chance. The way you have it, the second return will *never* be reached, so that is clearly wrong. And, as the error states, the view is not returning a response: which means that one of the if statements is false, and nothing is catching that.

Comment: then what is the solution?

Comment: Gettitn error for this line "user1 = UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('userid'))"